# slideToggle opens up element, but doesn't close it

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm making something really generic - just a collapsible menu list, actually i'm trying to emulate the wordpress admin menus. For some reason beyond my understanding, I manage to get slideToggle to slide open the menus, but they don't close back when I click on the toggle anchor again. This is the jquery:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {   
  $('.menu-collapse').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next('.admin-submenu').slideToggle();
  }); 
   });
```

This is the markup

```
<ul>
 <li class="top"><a href="" class="menu-item">Dashboard</a></a></li>
 <li class="top"><a href="" class="menu-item">Products</a><a href="" class="menu-collapse">
  <div class="admin-submenu">
   <ul>
    <li class="sub"><a href="">My Products</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="">Add New</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="top"><a href="" class="menu-item">Lists</a><a href="" class="menu-collapse">
  <div class="admin-submenu">
   <ul>       
    <li class="sub"><a href="">Brands</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="">Colors</a></li>       
    <li class="sub"><a href="">Locations</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="">Manufacturers</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As buh buh noted, your markup has several errors.  You have closing `</a>` tags with no matching opener, and opening `<a>` tags with no matching closer.  You could also simplify it quite a bit.  You don't need the `<div>`s, as the `<ul>` tags will serve perfectly well as containers for their list items.  Try using this as your markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="top"><a href="" class="menu-item">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="" class="menu-item">Products</a>
        <ul class="admin-submenu">
            <li class="sub"><a href="">My Products</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="">Add New</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="top"><a href="" class="menu-item">Lists</a>
        <ul class="admin-submenu">    
            <li class="sub"><a href="">Brands</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="">Colors</a></li>                          
            <li class="sub"><a href="">Locations</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="">Manufacturers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then in your jQuery, change the `.menu-collapse` selector to `.menu-item`.

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/zUf9W/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion Ender. I really appreciate the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML isn't valid.  You need to make sure that for each opening <a> tag you have exactly one matching closing tag: </a>

Comment: Oh shit.. I am so ashamed & embarassed of my stupid careless mistake. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is broken.  Your `a.menu-collapse` tags just open, but don't close.

As sidenotes, do you need the `div.admin-submenu`?  Or can you just give the admin-submenu class to the nested `ul`?  Also, the `a` inside the nested `li` is superfluous.  You shouldn't need it either for appearance or Javascript.